# Oscillatory part of Anderson localized wavefunction

Tags: condensed-matter, wavefunction, anderson-localization

In the context of Anderson localization, wavefunctions are localized on a scale of the localization length $\zeta$:
$$
|\psi(r)| = A\; exp(-|r|/\zeta)
$$
What is the oscillatory part of this wavefunction? I remember it having something to do with the Porter-Thomas distribution, but I forgot how. Any refs would be highly appreciated.